# How to wrap categoryAxis text in amchart v3?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I faced an issue `categoryAxis` and label text `overlaping` issue given below I mentioned the code.

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "labelRotation": 45,
    "autoWrap":true,
},
```

I uploaded my bug image so anyone please give me a solution to solve this.

[image: Uploaded My Result]

Here I mentioned my codepen link so please give me a solution to solve this.

https://codepen.io/arunram860/pen/aMPxKV

Comment: Can you share your complete chart config or create a code pen please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the direct [`categoryAxis.title`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/categoryaxis/#title_property) and [`valueAxis.title`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/valueaxis/#title_property) to create the axis names instead of creating the labels yourself in `allLabels`.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "valueAxes": [{
    "title": "Id"
  }],
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "labelRotation": 45,
    "title": "City Name"
  },
  // ...
});
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBMLgq) I forked your code pen to show you the configuration.